# Official Lightsail SSL with Really Simple SSL Plugin Wrong for Debian Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, debian, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Followed the steps to setup an SSL for Lightsail AWS (new instance running Debian) in the official docs here:

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress

Everything is absolutely fine until I reach section 8.

In section 8.1 is says:

Enter the following command to set your wp-config.php and htaccess.conf files to be writeable. The Really Simple SSL plugin will write to the wp-config.php file to configure your certificates.

sudo chmod 666 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php && sudo chmod 666 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf

However these paths don't exist in the Debian instance (used to work for Ubuntu instances).

The Really Simple SSL certificate says:

"No SSL detected"

How to install this properly on the newer Debian instances?

Comment: That doc is for the bitnami wordpress AMI, which is Ubuntu. You can setup letsencrypt on Debian, but that doc won't be very helpful for that (it wouldn't be good for vanilla Ubuntu either).

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The Bitnami WordPress directory structure changed a bit some months ago but it seems that the Lightsail documentation was not updated (please note that we do not maintain those guides). The WordPress files are now inside the /opt/bitnami/wordpress directory.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/understand-directory-structure/

Apart from that, I do now know why they are modifying the permissions of the htaccess.conf file so running these commands should be enough

```
sudo chmod 666 /opt/bitnami/wp-config.php
sudo chmod 666 /bitnami/wp-config.php
```

However, as I mentioned before, we do not maintain those guides. If you want to generate a SSL certificate, I suggest you take a look at this guide in the Bitnami documentation to generate a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate and redirect the requests to https if required.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/administration/generate-configure-certificate-letsencrypt/

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```